# How to specify the sequence the columns are presented from Oracle Apex report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have an Oracle APEX interactive report with a column with the name "sequence" and I want to specify the sequence the columns are presented.

The app I'm about making quizzes and the table I'm speaking about in the question is one where you select the questions for the quiz and, it has check-boxes to select the question but I want to specify the sequence in which these questions are displayed.

Comment: If you show the code you are using people will be able to provide more helpful responses.

Comment: the order that you want it to be displayed is based on your column "sequence"? If so, adding an "order by" clause in your interactive report wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Simpler title. Included question part of title in question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using an "order by sequence" clause in the sql query defining the interactive report, and make sure the columns are marked Enable Users To->sort->NO